# Logitech G Hub script - The code keeps running sometimes even after I release left mouse

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Even after I release left mouse the script would sometimes keep clicking by itself how do I stop this.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    Sleep(math.random(50, 75))
                    PressMouseButton(1)
                    Sleep(math.random(50, 75))
                    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end             
end
```

Comment: Why are you using the same button to trigger the event that you're simulating pressing from inside the event?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to both simulate LMB press/release and determine if it's pressed or released.

But there is a workaround: you can add alternative button for the same action as LMB.
For example, if LMB means "Fire" then add key "P" as alternative way to fire in the game.

```
local key_fire = "P"
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      Sleep(math.random(100, 150))
      while IsMouseButtonPressed(1) do
         Sleep(math.random(50, 75))
         PressKey(key_fire)
         Sleep(math.random(50, 75))
         ReleaseKey(key_fire)
      end
   end
end
```

You make the first shot by pressing LMB, and the script will make 2nd, 3rd,... shots by programmatically pressing <kbd>P</kbd> in the loop.