# How to make on LUA a repeat of the left mouse button clicks while the left mouse button is pressed?

Tags: loops, lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I need the left mouse button to repeat clicks every 100 ms while the left mouse button is pressed, but I can’t figure out how to do this. I found a similar script, but it either does not loop, or does not stop at all. How to do this if you press and release the button 1 is linked to the activation and it is also used.

```
          function Repeater()
  
  while IsMouseButtonPressed(1) do
    PressMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(100)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
  end
  repeat
    PressMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(100)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
  until IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
  end

function OnEvent(event, arg) 
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg) 
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then 
       Repeater() 
   end
end
```

Comment: What framework is this? You can probably a tag for that framework to your question.

Comment: LUA for mouse Logitech G series.Ty, tag added!

Comment: windows for example virtualizes mouse input, so left click to control left click, would not work as you intend

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I thought about it, but assumed that I was d*mb and maybe there are some "crutches" for this. Thanks for your reply, Sir!

Comment: It's impossible.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62164023/1847592)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It looks like what I need. Very grateful!